# Using the grep command with an array of words

Tags: bash, files, grep

I've got a text file with some lines and saved the text file into an array using

```
readarray -t array < Textfile
```

The Text file contains e.g. the following:

```
123
456
789
```

Now I'd like to use the grep command to look for the results in another text file using the array, so print out lines where "123", "456" or "789" appear.
To test the array thing, I tried to make grep look for "123", "456" and "789" the same text file and output the matching lines, if at least one of the three character series appears.

I tried

```
grep "${array[*]}" Textfile
```

but this doesn't show any results. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can't you simply use `grep -f`?

Comment: This will give me the error ": No such file or directory"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, you could just use the file itself. That is far simpler than trying to use a shell array:

```
grep -f file1.txt file2.txt
```

That will print any lines from `file2.txt` that match any lines in `file1.txt`.

If you *have* to use an array for some reason, things are more complicated. You can't just do `grep  "${array[*]}" Textfile` because `"${array[*]}"` will expand to the list of elements in the array separated by a space:

```
$ array=("foo" "bar" "baz")
$ echo "${array[*]}"
foo bar baz
```

Which means that your `grep` command would become:

```
grep 'foo bar baz' file
```

And that means "grep for `foo bar baz` in the file `file`". What you want to do is to grep for `foo`, *or* `bar`, *or* `baz`. This can be done using the -E option of `grep` and joining the patterns you want to search for with `|`:

```
grep -E 'foo|bar|baz' file
```

To do this, you will need to do something complicated like:

```
grep -E "$(printf '%s|' "${array[@]}" | sed 's/|$//')" file
```

Or perhaps:

```
grep -E "$(export IFS="|"; echo "${array[*]}")" file
```

On the whole, it's simply better, quicker and easier to use the file and forget about the array.

Comment: ... or you could build a new array with each original array entry preceded by `-e`: `pats=(); for pat in "${array[@]}"; do pats+=(-e "$pat"); done`.  Then `grep "${pats[@]}" file`

Comment: The answer of terdon works well!

Answer (score 1):

```
grep "${array[*]}" Textfile
```

Will work as long as you set `IFS` to newline (or anything that starts with newline), and use `--` or `-e` to make sure it still works even if the first element starts with `-`.

`"${array[*]}"` in Korn-like shells, like `"$*"` in POSIX shells expands to the list of elements joined with the first character of `$IFS`. The default value of `$IFS` is `<SPC><TAB><NL>` (`<SPC><TAB><NL><NUL>` in `zsh`), so by default, you'd get the element joined with SPC characters. For `grep`, you'd need the different regexps to be newline separated for `grep` to loop for each one in turn.

```
IFS=$'\n'
grep -e "${array[*]}" file
```

In `zsh`, doing `grep -e "${(pj:\n:)array}" file` (explicitly `j`oining with newline instead of modifying `$IFS` globally), or `grep -e$^array file` (which expands the array in `fish`/`rc`-style, where that becomes  `grep -efirst -esecond file` which is another way to supply several patterns to `grep`)  would be cleaner.

Another option is to  do:

```
printf '%s\n' "${array[@]}" | grep -f - file
```

This time passing the newline-delimited list of patterns over `grep`'s stdin rather than via an argument.

Those approaches would work whether your patterns are fixed strings (with `-F`), extended regexps (with `-E`) or basic regexps (default).

You may want to make sure the list of patterns is not empty:

```
(( ${#array[@]} > 0 )) && grep ...
```

Calling `grep` with an empty pattern yields different results depending on the `grep` implementation and generally not what you want.